# How can I call an external JS function from a jQuery script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Back to the time I was using **Node.js**, I used to use `fs.readFileSync(filename)` to call my external functions, where `filename` is the name of the file to load.

It might be weird but now that I am using jQuery, I'm kind of lost...

Currently I am gathering up **3** different files (one is `.html`, the two others are `.js`), and here is how they look :

Here is `test.html`

```
<body>
    <button id="submitting_button">Valider</button>

    <!--//////////////////////-->
    <!-- Loads jQuery library -->
    <script src="jQuery/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Loads my jQuery script -->
    <script src="jQuery/process.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

Here is `process.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submitting_button').click(function(){
        $.getScript("./functions/my_function.js");
        document.write(calculation());
    });
});
```

---

And finally, here is `my_function.js`

```
console.log("NOTE : my_function.js has been reached");
function calculation(){
    var result = 3+4;
    return result;
}
```

---

So when I click on the « Valider » button, nothing happens, except the fact that [Chrome console displays an error, noticing me that calculation is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJOom.png)... I am guessing that is because using `$.getScript()` is not a good thing, but I don't know any other function to load/read an external function.

Comment: Use callback method of getscript i.e. `$.getScript("./functions/my_function.js", function(){ document.write(calculation());});`

Comment: $.getScript()  is good, maybe the problem is the programmer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getScript()` is *asynchronous*, so the next line of code is trying to execute before that operation is completed.  Since the operation isn't completed, that function indeed doesn't exist yet.

(Note in your console that the error is happening *before* you log "my_function.js has been reached" to the console.)

Instead of executing it on the next line of code, execute it in the callback to `getScript()`:

```
$.getScript("./functions/my_function.js", function () {
    document.write(calculation());
});
```

That way it's invoked after the asynchronous operation has completed.

Side note: `document.write()` may or may not do whatever you expect here.  I'm honestly not sure where in the document this value would be written at this point.  It's better to get away from `document.write()` and instead set the value to an existing element in the HTML.  Something like:

```
$('#output').text(calculation());
```

where "output" would be the `id` of some element where you want to write the value:

```
<span id="output"></span>
```